# Как записать несколько чисел в одном рядке в массив

Tags: java, scanner

Дана задача, в которой надо ввести числа в массив, при этом, вводить их надо через пробел.

Comment: Если вы не закончили редактирование вопроса, но уже отправили, ничего страшного -  есть кнопка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/898563/edit).

Answer (score 1):

Например вот так:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Введите 5 чисел через запятую:");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] array = new int[5];
        for (int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            array[i]=scanner.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Ваш массив:");
        for (int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Результат будет таков:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если не хотите привязываться к размеру массива, то поиграйте с `ArrayList` вместо массива.

Answer (score 1):

Вы хотите использовать именно сканер? Скорее всего ваша задача на разделение строки.
Если это так, то у класса String есть метод split, который возвращает массив из "кусочков" исходной строки, которые разделены выражением из параметра.

```
    // считываем строку из консоли
    System.out.println("Введите несколько чисел через пробел (или не пробел)");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String str = reader.readLine();
    reader.close();

    // применяем метод split и получаем массив из строк
    // что такое "\\D+" ? это параметр метода split,
    // регулярное выражение, описывающее любое ненулевое количество не цифр
    // в частности пробел, попробуйте подставить " ", тоже сработает
    // но "\\D+" сработает независимо от того какие вообще символы между цифрами
    String[] splitStr = str.split("\\D+");

    // создаем массив из чисел, равный по длине массиву из строк
    // после разделения через "\\D+" в splitStr будут гарантированно цифры
    // попробуйте ввести "1 2 3 коза 4"
    int [] arr = new int[splitStr.length];

    // преобразуем каждую строку в число и записываем в ячейку с тем же номером
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(splitStr[i]);
    }

    // проверяем результат, воспользовавшись методом Arrays.toString
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```